# ST_Extrude function not found in PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I tried to run the following script on a PostgreSQL (v9.5.6) + PostGIS (v2.3.2) database:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    runway_area varchar;
    runway_area_transformed varchar;
BEGIN
    -- calculate runway area from centerline + width + strip --> buffer comes in handy here
    SELECT ST_Translate(
            ST_Force3D(
                ST_Buffer(
                    ST_GeomFromText(
                        'LINESTRING(16.553 48.122, 16.575 48.109)'
                    ),
                    0.0006,
                    'endcap=square'
                )
            ),
            0,
            0,
            180
        )
    INTO runway_area;
    RAISE NOTICE 'RUNWAY AREA: %', ST_AsGeoJSON(runway_area);

    SELECT ST_Extrude(ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(runway_area)), 0,0,50)
    INTO runway_area_transformed;
    RAISE NOTICE 'RUNWAY AREA TRANSFORMED: %', ST_AsGeoJSON(runway_area_transformed);
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I then get the following error:

```
ERROR:  function st_extrude(geometry, integer, integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT ST_Extrude(ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(runway_area)), 0...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT ST_Extrude(ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(runway_area)), 0,0,50)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 24 at SQL statement
********** Error **********

ERROR: function st_extrude(geometry, integer, integer, integer) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Context: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 24 at SQL statement
```

I soon found out that the function `st_extrude(geometry, integer, integer, integer)` does not exist in my database (I tried to look it up at Schemas > public > Functions, but it's not there).

I then started up a Docker container based on this (https://hub.docker.com/r/mdillon/postgis/) image (some PostGIS 2.3 on Postgres 9), but I couldn't find the function there either.

From the PostGIS documentation, it says that the `ST_Extrude` function should be available since v2.1.0 (see https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Extrude.html). Am I missing some very fundamental problem here why I don't have the function in my setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I figured out what the problem was: I missed the `postgis_sfcgal` extension. I ran `CREATE EXTENSION postgis_sfcgal;` and successfully installed the extension in my database. I could then run the above script!